# Log In lost due to memory loss

Tags: boot

Following illness when Ubuntu part installed on 64 bit AMD system I now do not know my Log In, can this be recovered/changed, or shall I wipe the hard drive and start again?

I have reset the Password, but cannot get past Log In as it always says it is 'Incorrect' - this is meant to be the latest Ubuntu, 14.04 I believe

I am not asking about Password but Log In

Comment: Case matters. If when you attempt to Login and it tells you the password is incorrect, then it is. Make sure you are using the correct CaSe in your password. The answer pointed to works.

Comment: If resetting the password doesn't help, this is probably not a duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](/q/24006). Please boot in single user mode, as you did to reset the password, and copy the content of `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, and `/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log`. Refer to [How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814) if necessary.

Comment: Remember: Case Matters I you are using the correct PasswOrd and/or UseRnaME with the wrong case it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1. Change `/etc/passwd` from another Linux instance, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165506/how-to-recover-linux-user-password):

   **Warning:** Only do this if you're in a reasonably safe environment (PC/laptop in   home or office) etc - don't do it on a Internet connected, `ssh` enabled server especially if the username in question is something common (such as `admin`) as the short window without a password may allow unwanted access to your server.

   1. Boot the computer with a LiveCD (any reasonable distro will do).
   2. Mount the system's root (`/`) partition somewhere (`/mnt` maybe) - make sure it's mounted read/write as you'll be editing a file on it.
   3. Edit `/etc/shadow` as user `root` (using `su` or `sudo`).
   4. Find the entry for your user and remove everything between the first and second colon (`:`) - it's a long string of random looking characters.
   5. Save the changes, unmount the partition and reboot into your normal system.
   6. Login with no password.
   7. Quickly set your user's password.
   8. Log out and in and check it works.
2. Use `passwd`, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126877/lost-password-for-a-user-on-a-linux-server-how-reset-it)

   If you use `passwd 16040` as root, it wont ask you about current password. You should consider, after changing password, to issue: `chage -d 0 16040` It will enforce changing user password, when user will login. It is best practice for security reasons.
3. Reboot and enter in passwordless mode, found [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/339)

   1. Reboot your computer / Turn your computer on.
   2. Hold down the `Shift` key at the start of the boot process to enable the GNU GRUB boot menu (if it does not show)
   3. Press `ESC` at the GNU GRUB prompt.
   4. Press `e` for edit.
   5. Use the `Arrow` keys to highlight the line that begins with kernel and press the e key.
   6. Go to the very end of the line and add `rw init=/bin/bash`
   7. Press `Enter` and then press `b` to boot your system.
   8. Your system will boot up to a passwordless root shell.
   9. Type in `passwd` yourusername
   10. Set your new password.
   11. Restart your system.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Edited according to your suggestions. Thanks ;)